# Github repository webhook error when creating AWS CodePipeline using Terraform

Tags: github, terraform, aws-codepipeline

I am receiving the following error when creating a Github repository webhook as part of CodePipeline.

github_repository_webhook.github_hook: Creating...
Error: POST https://api.github.com/repos/myrepoxx/static-web-example/hooks: 404 Not Found []

Tried changing the URL and repository with no success

hooks.tf

```
resource "aws_codepipeline_webhook" "codepipeline_webhook" {
  authentication  = "GITHUB_HMAC"
  name            = "codepipeline-webhook"
  target_action   = "Source"
  target_pipeline = aws_codepipeline.static_web_pipeline.name

  authentication_configuration {
    secret_token = random_string.github_secret.result
  }

  filter {
    json_path    = "$.ref"
    match_equals = "refs/heads/{Branch}"
  }
  tags = {}
}

resource "github_repository_webhook" "github_hook" {
  repository = var.repository_name
  events     = ["push"]

  configuration {
    url          = aws_codepipeline_webhook.codepipeline_webhook.url
    insecure_ssl = "0"
    content_type = "json"
    secret       = random_string.github_secret.result
  }
}

resource "random_string" "github_secret" {
  length  = 99
  special = false
}
```

var.tf

```
variable "env" {
  default     = "dev"
}

variable "region" {
  default     = "eu-west-1"
}

variable "repository_branch" {
  default     = "master"
}

variable "repository_owner" {
  default     = "myrepoxx"
}

variable "repository_name" {
  default     = "static-web-example"
}

variable "static_web_bucket_name" {
  default     = "myrepoxx-static-web-example-bucket"
}

variable "artifacts_bucket_name" {
  default     = "myrepoxx-static-web-example-artifacts"
}

variable "github_token" {
}

output "web_public_url" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.static_web_bucket.website_endpoint
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs), from terraform 0.13 onwards the github provider source should be `integrations/github`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    github = {
      source  = "integrations/github"
      version = "4.x.x"
    }
  }
}
```

then you can configure the provider to set your OAuth/personal access token if you need it

```
provider "github" {
  owner = var.repo_owner
  token = var.github_token
}
```